# Javascript d3.timeParse returning null

Tags: d3.js

I have a string like this:

`"[\&#39;2021_04_27__21_52_09\&#39;, \&#39;2021_04_27__21_52_13\&#39;, \&#39;2021_04_27__21_52_16\&#39;]"`,

and I separate out the date values and put them in an array like this:

`["2021_04_27__21_52_09",  "2021_04_27__21_52_13", "2021_04_27__21_52_16"]`.

I want to draw a line plot with these values on the x axis so I do

```
`var x_data = ["2021_04_27__21_52_09",  "2021_04_27__21_52_13", "2021_04_27__21_52_16"]
var timeParser = d3.timeParse("%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S");`
```

`timeParser(x_data)` returns null and I'm not sure why. How do I convert the x_data array into a format so that I can easily create d3 graph using the array as the x axis?

Answer (score 1):

First test:

```
timeParser("2021_04_27__21_52_09")
```

If that works, you need to map the function across your array:

```
let x = x_data.map(timeParser)
```

Answer (score -2):

Format your data strings correctly and convert to valid JS dates:

```
const data = ["2021_04_27__21_52_09",  "2021_04_27__21_52_13", "2021_04_27__21_52_16"];

const converted = data.map(d => {
  const date = d.substr(0, 10).replaceAll('_', "/");
  const time = d.substr(12).replaceAll('_', ':');
  return new Date(`${date} ${time}`);
});
```